# Can not use the xpath in headless mode of Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, headless

So I have a basic Selenium program which works perfectly without using headless mode but I don't want to Chrome appears each time when I run the program. for this reason I use headless mode but in that case Xpath don't works. I get the NoSuchElementException warning.
In my project I try to automatize the download data using Selenium and Pyqt5 just a few clicking but appearing Chrome in each time makes me annoying. Iread all the questions and many websites but can not find the solution. Thanks for your helping.

```
    import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget,QApplication,QRadioButton,QLabel,QPushButton,QVBoxLayout
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


browser_locale = 'locale-of-choice'
driver_path= "C:\\Users\\Bacanli\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe"
options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--window-size=1920, 1080')
options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
options.add_argument("--lang={}".format(browser_locale))
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu') 

browser=webdriver.Chrome(driver_path,options=options)
browser.get("http://www.bddk.org.tr/BultenHaftalik")

class Pencere(QWidget):
  
    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):

        self.radio_yazisi = QLabel("Hangi veriyi seçmek istiyorsun?")

        self.Krediler = QRadioButton("Krediler")
        self.Takipteki_alacaklar = QRadioButton("Takipteki Alacaklar")
        self.Menkul_Degerler = QRadioButton("Menkul Değerler")
        self.Mevduat = QRadioButton("Mevduat")
        self.Diger_Bilanco_Kalemleri = QRadioButton("Diğer Bilanço Kalemleri")
        self.Bilanco_disi_islemler = QRadioButton("Bilanço Dışı İşlemler")
        self.Bankalarda_saklanan_menkul_degerler1 = QRadioButton("Bankalarda Saklanan Menkul Değerler-1")
        self.Bankalarda_saklanan_menkul_degerler2 = QRadioButton("Bankalarda Saklanan Menkul Değerler-2")
        self.Yabancı_Para_Pozisyonu = QRadioButton("Yabancı Para Pozisyonu")

        

        self.buton = QPushButton("Gönder")

        v_box = QVBoxLayout()

        v_box.addWidget(self.Krediler)
        v_box.addWidget(self.Takipteki_alacaklar)
        v_box.addWidget(self.Menkul_Degerler)
        v_box.addWidget(self.Mevduat)
        v_box.addWidget(self.Diger_Bilanco_Kalemleri)
        v_box.addWidget(self.Bilanco_disi_islemler)
        v_box.addWidget(self.Bankalarda_saklanan_menkul_degerler1)
        v_box.addWidget(self.Bankalarda_saklanan_menkul_degerler2)
        v_box.addWidget(self.Yabancı_Para_Pozisyonu)

        v_box.addStretch()
        v_box.addWidget(self.buton)

        self.setLayout(v_box)

        self.buton.clicked.connect(lambda : self.click(self.Krediler.isChecked(),self.Takipteki_alacaklar.isChecked(),
                                                       self.Menkul_Degerler.isChecked(),self.Mevduat.isChecked(),
                                                       self.Diger_Bilanco_Kalemleri.isChecked(),
                                                       self.Bilanco_disi_islemler.isChecked(),self.Bankalarda_saklanan_menkul_degerler1.isChecked(),
                                                       self.Bankalarda_saklanan_menkul_degerler2.isChecked(),self.Yabancı_Para_Pozisyonu.isChecked()))

        self.setWindowTitle("BDDK")

        self.show()
        
    
    def click(self,Krediler,Takipteki_alacaklar,Menkul_Degerler,Mevduat,Diger_Bilanco_Kalemleri,Bilanco_disi_islemler,
              Bankalarda_saklanan_menkul_degerler1,Bankalarda_saklanan_menkul_degerler2,Yabancı_Para_Pozisyonu):
       

       
        if Krediler:
            
            self.tikla_kredi=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tabloListesiItem-253']/span")
            self.tikla_kredi.click()
            self.kredi_df = pd.read_html(browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='Tablo']").get_attribute('outerHTML'))[0]
            
        if Takipteki_alacaklar:
            
            self.tikla_Takipteki_alacaklar=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tabloListesiItem-254']/span")
            self.tikla_Takipteki_alacaklar.click() 
            self.Takipteki_alacaklar_df = pd.read_html(browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='Tablo']").get_attribute('outerHTML'))[0]                 
            print(self.Takipteki_alacaklar_df)
        
        if Menkul_Degerler:
            
            self.tikla_Menkul_Degerler=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tabloListesiItem-255']/span")
            self.tikla_Menkul_Degerler.click()
            self.Menkul_Degerler_df = pd.read_html(browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='Tablo']").get_attribute('outerHTML'))[0]
      
        if Mevduat:
            
            self.tikla_Mevduat=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tabloListesiItem-256']/span")
            self.tikla_Mevduat.click()
            self.Menkul_Degerler_df = pd.read_html(browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='Tablo']").get_attribute('outerHTML'))[0]
        if Diger_Bilanco_Kalemleri:
            
            self.tikla_Diger_Bilanco_Kalemleri=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tabloListesiItem-257']/span")
            self.tikla_Diger_Bilanco_Kalemleri.click()
            self.Menkul_Degerler_df = pd.read_html(browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='Tablo']").get_attribute('outerHTML'))[0]
        if Bilanco_disi_islemler:
            
            self.tikla_Bilanco_disi_islemler=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tabloListesiItem-258']/span")
            self.tikla_Bilanco_disi_islemler.click()
            self.Bilanco_disi_islemler_df = pd.read_html(browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='Tablo']").get_attribute('outerHTML'))[0]
      
        if Bankalarda_saklanan_menkul_degerler1:
            
            self.tikla_Bankalarda_saklanan_menkul_degerler1=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tabloListesiItem-259']/span")
            self.tikla_Bankalarda_saklanan_menkul_degerler1.click()
            self.Bankalarda_saklanan_menkul_degerler1_df = pd.read_html(browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='Tablo']").get_attribute('outerHTML'))[0]
    
        if Bankalarda_saklanan_menkul_degerler2:
           
            self.tikla_Bankalarda_saklanan_menkul_degerler2=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tabloListesiItem-260']/span")
            self.tikla_Bankalarda_saklanan_menkul_degerler2.click()
            self.Bankalarda_saklanan_menkul_degerler2_df = pd.read_html(browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='Tablo']").get_attribute('outerHTML'))[0]
       
        if Yabancı_Para_Pozisyonu:
            
            self.tikla_Yabancı_Para_Pozisyonu=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tabloListesiItem-261']/span")
            self.tikla_Yabancı_Para_Pozisyonu.click()
            self.Yabancı_Para_Pozisyonu_df = pd.read_html(browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='Tablo']").get_attribute('outerHTML'))[0]
            

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

pencere = Pencere()

sys.exit(app.exec_())



print(df)


browser.close()
```

Comment: What exactly XPath / code line here is working correctly in regular mode but throws exception in headless mode?

Comment: @Prophet under the click() class for each case there are 9 different xpath line.

Comment: I see more, but what line is failing?

Comment: @Prophet there are 9 cases wherever you click that xpath can not be find.

Comment: But program is throwing an exception on the first of them. Once exception occurred it doesn't continue further..

Comment: @Prophet But the program works without headless and also xpath line changes in error area each time you click.